# What are these lines that connect into cells called?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

I just recently watched a very interesting video that showed cell division under a microscope. In the video, you can see cells that have either one, two or more lines connected to them. What are these called?

Source: https://youtu.be/rgLJrvoX_qo[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me to which lines you are referring to.

Comment: I added a photo and I apologize for the confusion. You can see multiple strands going off from each cell in photo.

Comment: I think it's likely they are filopodia; however, without knowing more background on the image and what cells we are looking at and under what conditions I'd leave that as just a hesitant guess.

Comment: @Bryan Krause I believe you are correct and thank you so much. I am reading into what exactly this Filopodia is and what it does. Thanks for sharing something new with me I love to learn. I don't know how to upvote but just wanted to say thank you.